# error: expected primary-expression before 'result'

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

int main//I find there missing a (),it my fault,2017.4.19
{
    vector<int> result;
    int temp;
    cout<<"请输入一串数字：(ctrl+D结束输入)"<<endl;
    while(cin>>temp)
    {
        result.push_back(temp);
    }
    vector<int>::size_type index;
    for(index=0; index<result.size()-1; index+=2)
    {
        cout<<result[index]+result[index+1]<<"\t";
    }
    if(index==result.size()-1)
        cout<<result[index];

    return 0;
}
```

but i meet "error: expected primary-expression before 'result'" when in this line
"vector result;"

and I just don't understand why

Comment: Add `()` after `int main`.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm not serious enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two errors:

```
int main() {
//      ^ ---- here

  vector<int>::size_type index;
  //    ^---- here
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my mistake